# Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: php, apache, xampp, composer-php, slim

I am following a tutorial to create a http server using Apache, Xampp, [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/request.html) and php.
I am used to javaScript and Express, so I'm a bit lost here.

Here's how to folder organised:
[image]

user.php

```
<?php
$app->get('/app/test', function (Request $request) {
 echo "hello world";
});
?>
```

app.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
$app = AppFactory::create();
include __DIR__ . '/../app/user.php';
?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
$app->run();
?>
```

In order to test this, I type

```
http://localhost/friendster/app/test
```

And this is what I get:
[image]
**NOTE:** The Apache server works correctly:
[image]
Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: You are trying to get `friendster/app/test` but the route is defined as `/app/test`.

Comment: @yivi http://localhost/app/test doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Create a second `.htaccess` file in your project root-directory and copy/paste this content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

The second `.htaccess` file is important to run your Slim app in a sub-directory and within your development environment.

After `$app = AppFactory::create();` add this line:

```php
$app->setBasePath('/friendster');
```

[Slim 4 - Apache URL rewriting](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html#apache-url-rewriting)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why does a second htaccess solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by simply starting from scratch and using the ***[Slim Framework 4 Skeleton Application](http://%20https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton)*** and following the [official tutorial](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html) to create the first app.

Make sure to install the app using the commands mentioned in the github repo, **NOT MANUALLY**, otherwise you will face the problem I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731117/warning-requirec-xampp-htdocs-phpslimhttpserver-public-vendor-autoload-php):

So do like this:

> composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton [my-app-name]

And then:

> cd [my-app-name] composer start

And you will something like this:

[image]

The result is this:
[image]